# Links not displayed in IE10 when another element has CSS3 animation

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

I am trying to create a header with CSS3 animation and I am encountering a problem. The problem is that the menu links do not show up in IE10 on load. However, the menu items do show up when I randomly move the mouse over the area where the links should have been present.

I searched a lot but cannot find the root-cause. However, I managed to sort of figure out that this happens only in IE10 and that too only when the animation is enabled.

Below, I have included two jsFiddle versions. One is without animation property where the menu is displayed correctly. The other is with animation where the menu doesn't show up.

[**With Animation**](http://jsfiddle.net/rT3Uk/) | [**Without Animation**](http://jsfiddle.net/rT3Uk/1/)

**Note:**

1. There are no issues in Chrome 30, FireFox 23, Opera 15 and Safari
   5.1.7
2. The Heading and Sub-heading will have multi-lingual text which would be fetched from Database. Hence I don't want to do this
   animation with images. I am also not looking for any JavaScript or
   jQuery alternates/work-arounds.

**HTML**

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="banner" class="banner left">
        <div id="first_line">Heading</div>
        <div>Sub-heading</div>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mselected">Link5</li>
            <li><a href="#">Link6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
#header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.banner {
    cursor: default;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: entry 2s linear 2s 5 alternate;
    -moz-animation: entry 2s linear 2s 5 alternate;
    animation: entry 2s linear 2s 5 alternate; /* This seems to cause the problem */
}
@-webkit-keyframes entry {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) rotateX(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.625) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.875) rotateX(270deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotateX(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes entry {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.5) rotateX(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: scale(0.625) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: scale(0.875) rotateX(270deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1) rotateX(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes entry {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5) rotateX(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.625) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    75% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.875) rotateX(270deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotateX(360deg);
    }
}
.menu {
    padding-right: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
#first_line {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.menu ul {
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.menu li a {
    color: white;
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.menu li:hover a, .menu li a:hover {
    color: black;
}
.mselected {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me in IE 10.0.9200.16660 (Updateversion: 10.0.08 KB2862772) on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue is caused due to the `delay` set for the animation. If we remove the delay, it works as expected and the links are displayed on page load. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mNGgy/1/)

```
animation: entry 2s linear 5 alternate;
```

**Note:** This is just a work-around solution. I will update if I manage to find out the reason why it doesn't work with animation delay.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help on this. I can live without the delay for now..would have given an upvote but I dont have enough reputation to do that. I will wait for a while to see if there is any other answer and would accept yours if there is none better.